# Why does my Flutter custom ScrollPhysics break GestureDetectors in the Scrollable?

Tags: flutter, scrollview, gesturedetector

Why does my Flutter custom ScrollPhysics break GestureDetectors in my Scrollable? I am using a SingleChildScrollView that uses a custom ScrollPhysics I wrote, and for some reason the GestureDetectors I have in the ScrollView don't react to touch at all, UNLESS the ScrollView is in overscroll.

Basically, unless I just recently scrolled to the scroll extent and the ScrollView is stopped at the scroll extent, I can't detect any gestures inside of the custom physics ScrollView. Detecting gestures inside of a normal ScrollView works just fine, of course.

[Here's a video of my predicament; the blue ScrollView on the left uses the default ScrollPhysics and the amber one on the right uses my custom ScrollPhysics, with five tappable boxes in each ScrollView:](https://youtu.be/EtalLjr_n-g)

[Here's the GitHub:](https://github.com/norrisduncan/problems/blob/master/FlutterSingleChildScrollViewAbsorbsGesturesExample)

And here's the code itself:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/physics.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  runApp(FlutterSingleChildScrollViewAbsorbsGesturesExample());
}

class FlutterSingleChildScrollViewAbsorbsGesturesExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<FlutterSingleChildScrollViewAbsorbsGesturesExample> createState() =>
      FlutterSingleChildScrollViewAbsorbsGesturesExampleState();
}

class FlutterSingleChildScrollViewAbsorbsGesturesExampleState
    extends State<FlutterSingleChildScrollViewAbsorbsGesturesExample> {
  Color colorOfRegularPhysicsBoxOne = Colors.black;
  Color colorOfRegularPhysicsBoxTwo = Colors.black;
  Color colorOfRegularPhysicsBoxThree = Colors.black;
  Color colorOfRegularPhysicsBoxFour = Colors.black;
  Color colorOfRegularPhysicsBoxFive = Colors.black;

  Color colorOfCustomPhysicsBoxOne = Colors.black;
  Color colorOfCustomPhysicsBoxTwo = Colors.black;
  Color colorOfCustomPhysicsBoxThree = Colors.black;
  Color colorOfCustomPhysicsBoxFour = Colors.black;
  Color colorOfCustomPhysicsBoxFive = Colors.black;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'An example of how the SingleChildScrollView with custom ScrollPhysics looks like it is eating gestures '
          'meant for its descendants',
      home: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              height: 1400.0,
              width: 200.0,
              color: Colors.lightBlue,
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => setState(() {
                            colorOfRegularPhysicsBoxOne = Colors.white;
                          }),
                      child: Container(
                        color: colorOfRegularPhysicsBoxOne,
                        height: 100.0,
                        width: 100.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => setState(() {
                            colorOfRegularPhysicsBoxTwo = Colors.white;
                          }),
                      child: Container(
                        color: colorOfRegularPhysicsBoxTwo,
                        height: 100.0,
                        width: 100.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => setState(() {
                            colorOfRegularPhysicsBoxThree = Colors.white;
                          }),
                      child: Container(
                        color: colorOfRegularPhysicsBoxThree,
                        height: 100.0,
                        width: 100.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => setState(() {
                            colorOfRegularPhysicsBoxFour = Colors.white;
                          }),
                      child: Container(
                        color: colorOfRegularPhysicsBoxFour,
                        height: 100.0,
                        width: 100.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => setState(() {
                            colorOfRegularPhysicsBoxFive = Colors.white;
                          }),
                      child: Container(
                        color: colorOfRegularPhysicsBoxFive,
                        height: 100.0,
                        width: 100.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: CustomSnappingScrollPhysicsForTheControlPanelHousing(stoppingPoints: [
              0.0,
              100.0,
              200.0,
              300.0,
              400.0,
            ]),
            child: Container(
              height: 1400.0,
              width: 200.0,
              color: Colors.amberAccent,
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => setState(() {
                            colorOfCustomPhysicsBoxOne = Colors.white;
                          }),
                      child: Container(
                        color: colorOfCustomPhysicsBoxOne,
                        height: 100.0,
                        width: 100.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => setState(() {
                            colorOfCustomPhysicsBoxTwo = Colors.white;
                          }),
                      child: Container(
                        color: colorOfCustomPhysicsBoxTwo,
                        height: 100.0,
                        width: 100.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => setState(() {
                            colorOfCustomPhysicsBoxThree = Colors.white;
                          }),
                      child: Container(
                        color: colorOfCustomPhysicsBoxThree,
                        height: 100.0,
                        width: 100.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => setState(() {
                            colorOfCustomPhysicsBoxFour = Colors.white;
                          }),
                      child: Container(
                        color: colorOfCustomPhysicsBoxFour,
                        height: 100.0,
                        width: 100.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => setState(() {
                            colorOfCustomPhysicsBoxFive = Colors.white;
                          }),
                      child: Container(
                        color: colorOfCustomPhysicsBoxFive,
                        height: 100.0,
                        width: 100.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomSnappingScrollPhysicsForTheControlPanelHousing extends ScrollPhysics {
  List<double> stoppingPoints;
  SpringDescription springDescription = SpringDescription(mass: 100.0, damping: .2, stiffness: 50.0);

  @override
  CustomSnappingScrollPhysicsForTheControlPanelHousing({@required this.stoppingPoints, ScrollPhysics parent})
      : super(parent: parent) {
    stoppingPoints.sort();
  }

  @override
  CustomSnappingScrollPhysicsForTheControlPanelHousing applyTo(ScrollPhysics ancestor) {
    return new CustomSnappingScrollPhysicsForTheControlPanelHousing(
        stoppingPoints: stoppingPoints, parent: buildParent(ancestor));
  }

  @override
  Simulation createBallisticSimulation(ScrollMetrics scrollMetrics, double velocity) {
    double targetStoppingPoint = _getTargetStoppingPointPixels(scrollMetrics.pixels, velocity, 0.0003, stoppingPoints);

    return ScrollSpringSimulation(springDescription, scrollMetrics.pixels, targetStoppingPoint, velocity,
        tolerance: Tolerance(velocity: .00003, distance: .003));
  }

  double _getTargetStoppingPointPixels(
      double initialPosition, double velocity, double drag, List<double> stoppingPoints) {
    double endPointBeforeSnappingIsCalculated =
        initialPosition + (-velocity / math.log(drag)).clamp(stoppingPoints[0], stoppingPoints.last);
    if (stoppingPoints.contains(endPointBeforeSnappingIsCalculated)) {
      return endPointBeforeSnappingIsCalculated;
    }
    if (endPointBeforeSnappingIsCalculated > stoppingPoints.last) {
      return stoppingPoints.last;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < stoppingPoints.length; i++) {
      if (endPointBeforeSnappingIsCalculated < stoppingPoints[i] &&
          endPointBeforeSnappingIsCalculated < stoppingPoints[i] - (stoppingPoints[i] - stoppingPoints[i - 1]) / 2) {
        double stoppingPoint = stoppingPoints[i - 1];
        debugPrint(stoppingPoint.toString());
        return stoppingPoint;
      } else if (endPointBeforeSnappingIsCalculated < stoppingPoints[i] &&
          endPointBeforeSnappingIsCalculated > stoppingPoints[i] - (stoppingPoints[i] - stoppingPoints[i - 1]) / 2) {
        double stoppingPoint = stoppingPoints[i];
        debugPrint(stoppingPoint.toString());
        return stoppingPoint;
      }
    }
    throw Error.safeToString('Failed finding a new scroll simulation endpoint for this scroll animation');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found my own answer -

It turns out that my Scrollable's ScrollPosition was constantly calling goBallistic(velocity:0.0) on itself, which means that it wasn't animating, but it never went idle, so it was locked into a state where it didn't respond to pointer events.

The problem was with the BallisticScrollActivity, the portion of a fling on a scrollable that occurs after the pointer comes off the screen. Once a BallisticScrollAcitivity ends, its ScrollPosition calls ScrollPositionWithSingleContext.goBallistic(velocity: 0.0), which creates a simulation using the current ScrollPhysics' ScrollPhysics.createBallisticSimulation(scrollMetrics:this, velocity:0.0).

```
   BallisticScrollActivity._end() => 
   ScrollPositionWithSingleContext.goBallistic(velocity: 0.0) =>
   ScrollPhysics.createBallisticSimulation(scrollMetrics:this, velocity:0.0)
```

However, the default ScrollPhysics has an if statement that says to return null if the current velocity is zero:

```
   if (velocity.abs() < tolerance.velocity)
      return null;
```

and ScrollPositionWithSingleContext.createBallisticSimulation calls ScrollPositionWithSingleContext.goIdle() if the Simulation it receives is null:

```
final Simulation simulation = physics.createBallisticSimulation(this, velocity);
if (simulation != null) {
  beginActivity(new BallisticScrollActivity(this, simulation, context.vsync));
} else {
  goIdle();
}
```

which disposes of the BallisticScrollActivity and Animations and allows the Scrollable to respond to touch events again.

So all I had to do was add

```
if (velocity.abs() < .0003) {
  return null;
}
```

to my CustomScrollPhysics' createBallisticSimulation() before I returned my CustomScrollSimulation, and everything works pretty well.

Of course, there's the problem that there is no way to register a tap on a moving GestureDetector without first stopping the Scrollable from scrolling, which feels awful, but every app has that problem.

Hope this helps!